# Threebox with tile suorce

Tags: javascript, 3d, mapbox-gl-js, threebox

I'm new to threeBox and I'm developing a mapbox-gl-js map that has a 3D buildings (fill-extrusion) layer from tiles source. I want to add a symbol/icon layer with elevation from tile source useing threeBox (like icon over special buildings etc.). 
From what I have seen so far threeBox layers in Mapbox can be added only GeoJson sources, is it possible to add to threeBox layer a tiles source as one adds to MapBox layers? 
 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess ThreeBox doesn't support vector tiles.

You may be able to hack something to work by using `map.querySourceFeatures()` to access all the buildings in the loaded viewport as GeoJSON, then using that. There are lots of caveats that you will discover. :)